# Question about relations and ordered pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

[image: Question]

I am not sure how to determine if the ordered pairs are in the relation. I kind of have a gut feeling that 7 a) c) are in the relation, but not sure about b)

Also can someone help me with question 8 as well?

Edit:
I hope it is not too much to ask, but can someone tell me the answers? I need them to study for a upcoming exam. Thanks

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  your relation consists of ordered pairs of ordered pairs.  For a, you are supposed to find all pairs of the corners of the square that are part of the relation.  Start with the first one:  is $((0,0),(0,0))$ in the relation?  Plug the numbers into the definition and see if it comes out TRUE.  You should notice a pattern, so will not have to check all $16$ pairs of pairs.  b works exactly the same way-I don't know why each point is listed twice.  Having done a and b, you should have an idea how it works, so can make a general statement for c whether $(w,w),(z,z))$ is part of the relation.

For 8, look at the definitions of those terms and see if the relation fits them.

Comment: thank you for replying. However I realized that I did not understand the original question. So the question is ask me to list the ordered pairs that are in each of U's defined in a) b) c) ?

Comment: No, let's take a simpler example.  If the relation were the standard $\le, U$ would consist of numbers.  Say $U=\{1,2,3\}$.  Then you would be asked to find the pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x,y \in U, x\le y$  Your answer would be $\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3)\}$  Now $U$ has ordered pairs, so the relation is pairs of ordered pairs.  Intuitively, the relation says the first point is below and to the left of the second pair.